# I'm having trouble center-aligning a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I have a header for a website like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4hjp.png

And I'm trying to align the navigation menu to the center. The navigation div is inside the center columnn (in black) and the CSS for it is:

```
.nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 287px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

At the moment, each button in the navigation is yet another div. If someone has suggestions about how to approach it without having so many divs I would appreciate it, but anyway the code for the buttons is:

```
.button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 135px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #aa0000;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

I have even tried setting text-align in body to center, but it won't work. How can I center align this menu?

Comment: We need to see the HTML structure but if the `.button` divs are children of the `.nav`...change `float:left` to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: it only seems to work when .nav's width is not in percentage form, but that brings other problems with it (not being viewed correctly at lower resolutions)

Comment: Not sure about your first point but lower resolutions would be handled by media queries...there is no universal "one thing" to responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is the `"float:left"` on your divs that makes them stay left aligned. Replace that float with `"display:inline-block;"` and you are fine.
And, if you don't want to use those divs, you could try to go with a list. 
A common practice for menus is something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu item a</li>
  <li>Menu item b</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles:

```
.centerDiv { 
            width: 60%; 
            height:70px; 
            margin: 0 auto; 
            text-align: center;
            top: 287px;
            z-index: 100;
        } 

        .buttonDiv { 
            width: 10%; 
            height:40px; 
            background-color:#aa0000; 
            float:left; 
            margin-left: 10px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 40px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Markup:

```
<div class="centerDiv">
            <div class="buttonDiv">Button 1</div>
            <div class="buttonDiv">Button 2</div>
            <div class="buttonDiv">Button 3</div>
            <div class="buttonDiv">Button 4</div>
            <div class="buttonDiv">Button 5</div>
            <div class="buttonDiv">Button 6</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the self-answer, but none of the answers solved the problem exactly. Apparently the nav container width being set to 100% prevented any centering. After setting it to a static value, I was able to align normally. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Use `<a>` instead of divs you can make it look attractive like

```
a{
display:block;
background-color:red;
width:100px;
}
```

then use `text-align:center` it will align

Comment: thanks, this is much better, but it still won't align :(

Comment: @otmeek did you try text align on the div that contains the buttons?

Comment: yep, at this point, I've tried text-align:center on every div in this thing

Comment: @otmeek you tried this after making the buttons like i said right? Oterwise the float left will make it align left

Comment: yes I did, except I used inline-block for display instead of just block because they were placed under each other.

Comment: @otmeek ok can you provide a link to your site?